# Class acting like a Generic Stack?

Tags: c#, .net, stack

I am still learning basics of C# and found this unfinished class task that really confused me. To me, it looks like a class that is supposed to have a generic Stack's methods, constructors, and its property. But that hardly makes sense to me.

I know generic stacks are collections, but I don't know how to approach making a class similar to it or maybe it's about making a class that acts like a Stack class, I am honestly not sure.

The big thing that confused me was the parameterless methods and constructors, how would one even go about making them work if they are supposed to be parameterless?

I know from documentation that generic StackT has all of these methods, constructors and a property, but I have no idea how to implement them in this class and in this manner. How would one even pass anything to this class?

Please help make sense of it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GenericStackTask
{
    /// Represents stack of the specified type T.
    /// <typeparam name="T">Specifies the type of elements in the stack.</typeparam>
    public class Stack<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        /// Initializes a new instance of the stack class that is empty and has the default initial capacity.
 
        private Stack _stack;

        public Stack()
        {
            Stack myStack = new Stack();
        }

        /// Initializes a new instance of the stack class that is empty and has
        /// the specified initial capacity.
        /// <param name="capacity">The initial number of elements of stack.</param>

        public Stack(int capacity)
        {
            Stack myStack = new Stack(capacity);
            _stack = myStack;
            _count = capacity;
        }

        /// Initializes a new instance of the stack class that contains elements copied from the specified collection and has sufficient capacity to accommodate the number of elements copied.
        /// <param name="collection">The collection to copy elements from.</param>

        public Stack(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            Stack mystack = 
            _stack = mystack;
        }

        /// Gets the number of elements contained in the stack.

        public int Count => throw new NotImplementedException();

        /// Removes and returns the object at the top of the stack.
        /// <returns>The object removed from the top of the stack.</returns>

        public T Pop()
        {
            new Stack(_stack);
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// Returns the object at the top of the stack without removing it.
        /// <returns>The object at the top of the stack.</returns>
        public T Peek()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// Inserts an object at the top of the stack.
        /// <param name="item">The object to push onto the stack.
        /// The value can be null for reference types.</param>

        public void Push(T item)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

       /// Copies the elements of stack to a new array.
       /// <returns>A new array containing copies of the elements of the stack

        public T[] ToArray()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// Determines whether an element is in the stack.
        /// <param name="item">The object to locate in the stack. The value can be null for reference types.</param>
        /// <returns>Return true if item is found in the stack; otherwise, false.

        public bool Contains(T item)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes all objects from the stack.
        /// </summary>
        public void Clear()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        /// Returns an enumerator for the stack.
        /// <returns>Return Enumerator object for the stack.</returns>

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the idea was to make a generic wrapper around the non-generic [`Stack` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack?view=net-6.0) similar to [`Stack<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=net-6.0). A `Stack` holds items of type `object` so basically each item can be of every possible type. The wrapper would use a `Stack` internally, but would make sure only elements of type `T` could be inserted and when an item is retrieved it would cast it to `T`. It's very much unfinished though.

Comment: This was probably originally written before the `Stack<T>` class was available in the CLR.